# When I pop a controller, the nav separate from the controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I set the nav backColor is ClearColor, but it caused when I pop the controller that the nav separate the controller, I do not know how to solove the problem.

Comment: not clearly understand question! what do you mean by `it caused when i pop the controller that the nav separate the controller` this statement ?

Comment: try to explain more and clearly about your problem

Comment: sorroy ,i come from china ,my english is poor,how post a gif in stackoverflow to explain my problem

Answer (score 0):

Its can be, because you call pop on another viewController, try to find your rootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your popover on the presentedViewController at screen as it will not move to another to display it.